# Time-varying variables in Cox regression- can I fix them?

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have a clinical dataset with variables measured over a number of years at various assessment time points. This data was not intended for research initially which is why there are some challenges.

Ideally, an extended Cox model would be most beneficial, however, due to the data collection for certain time-varying variables being reported only in cumulative form, I have had to 'fix' some of these variables at a certain time.

To give an example, a variable measuring the number of accommodation moves, was updated every time a participant moved, meaning that this variable is not possible to input at the different times.

My question is, is it ok to take 'time-varying variables' and essentially fix them in time, eg. total number of accommodation moves at death/censoring?

I know this is not ideal, but it is the best I can do with the dataset I have. For some variables, like sex it is not a problem, but I am interested in the number of moves and when I use 'total number of moves', this gives a significant result in the model.

I am just curious as to whether it is interpretable given I have 'fixed' it at a certain time-point.

Comment: Why can't you use the time-varying variables as they are?  There are widely used methods to deal with covariates that change over time in time-to-event analysis.  (In short, when a covariate changes you censor the participant then start them again as a new participant with delayed entry at the new value).

'total number of moves at end of study' will likely be linked to survival time as people who survive longer will have the opportunity to accrue more moves.  If you add more detail about why you can't apply the usual methods for time-varying covariates you might get a better answer.

Comment: Hi George, I mentioned it is because I only have the cumulative data. The data was collected at different times but not reported at these times, but rather added to a 'total'.

Comment: Ah, I understood 'cumulative' to mean 'as it accumulated'!  So you only have a single value for that person recorded at the end of the study (if they died or were censored?)

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is the case for a few of the variables- mainly those that were updated when changes occurred. I do have the total number of moves prior to the start of the study. So I could calculate change only occurring during the study and then control for the total number of assessments. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing things though.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I agree it feels like somehow normalizing or controlling the total moves for the time spend in the study should work.  A case control study might also work if you have enough people who die or are censored at similar times so their 'number of moves' would be directly comparable?

Comment: Thanks George, I will have a go at controlling for the number of assessments and see whether this affects the outcome.

Comment: I'm highly suspicious that using an end-of study cumulative total will be valid, even if it's normalized by something like time-in-study. It seems like that will violate a key rule that "you cannot look into the future" https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf. If a person had 1 move at year 5 and a second move at year 10 just before they left the study, then any "moves per year" variable when measured at year 9 should be 1/9, not 1/5. That said, I could be wrong and haven't thought much about this.